# html-engine-mini for Unity HtmlGUI.Label()

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm trying to create a Html label using html-engine-mini for Unity
but the HtmlGUI.Label() seems not working well (it displays nothing)
here is the code i wrote:

[image]

the GUI.Label is working just fine

any ideas?

Comment: Did you try GUI.Label(new Rect(..) @"HtmlString");?

Comment: Absolutely yes, it shows the string as is

Answer (score 0):

i've figured it out finally, seems i forgot to initialize my HTML Engine

```
//Initialize the HTML Engine
HtEngine.RegisterDevice(new HtmlDevice());

//Initialize the HTML Logger
HtEngine.RegisterLogger(new HtmlLogger());
```